# Laravel 5 Seeding Pivot Tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was watching the following lesson and was following along with Roles and Permissions however now I"m to seeding my pivot table with a Seeder class but not sure how I should accomplish this.

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/16

This is the sort of thing I have right now but obviously with the givePermissionTo() inside of the Role model I'm sure there is a better way of handling this. I have a feeling I don't even need a PermissionRole model. The big issue here is that I run it for all 5 different roles and about 63 different permissions.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\PermissionRole;

class PermissionRoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        PermissionRole::create([
            'role_id' => 5,
            'permission_id' => '1',
        ]);

        PermissionRole::create([
            'role_id' => 5,
            'permission_id' => '2',
        ]);

        PermissionRole::create([
            'role_id' => 5,
            'permission_id' => '3',
        ]);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

    public function givePermissionTo(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->permissions()->save();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Can someone hint as to what that is?

Answer (score 0):

You usually shouldn't have a model for your pivot table, although there are times when it makes sense to have it in the event you have an additional key in the pivot table which points to a table which isn't part of the belongs to many relationship.  For example, if you had a `created_by` field in your pivot table which would be the id of the user which created that relation.

With that said, it also should not hurt anything to have a model for your pivot table to help you work with it directly like you are doing.

To see the table without the model, I'd use the Laravel functions provided.  I don't know how that `givePermissionTo` function is supposed to work because you aren't actually using the argument provided.

I'd put some constraints on this, but one way you could do it would be to use the `sync` function.  This will give all roles all permissions.

```
$roles = \App\Role::all();
$permissions = \App\Permission::all();

foreach($roles as $role) {
    $role->permissions()->sync($permissions);
}
```